# I want to loop through all possible combinations of values of a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary where each value is a list of lists.

Something like:

```
sites = {'e1': [[0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3]], 'e2': [[0, 1, 4], [0, 3, 4]]}
```

I want to loop through all possible combinations (i.e. pairs in my example) of lists (i.e. one list of `e1` + one list of `e2`, etc.).

Better with the example:

I want to loop through all these combinations:

```
[0, 1, 3]; [0, 1, 4]
[0, 1, 3]; [0, 3, 4]
[0, 2, 3]; [0, 1, 4]
[0, 2, 3]; [0, 3, 4]
```

This example dictionary has two keys but in practice I do not know how many keys I'll have in my dictionary. It could be more than two.

Can you help?

Comment: See the dupe; `itertools.product(*sites.values())` will do this.

Comment: Or `list(reduce(product, sites.values()))`

Comment: Depends whether you want to obtain 2-tuples or n-tuples (for n entries in the dict). `itertools.product` will yield n-tuples. With `itertools.combinations` you can specify the tuple length.

Comment: @a_guest: It looks like n-tuples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for *cartesian product* between the *list* values of the dict. For achieving the desired result, you may use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) as:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> sites = {'e1': [[0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3]], 'e2': [[0, 1, 4], [0, 3, 4]]}

>>> list(product(*sites.values()))
[([0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 4]), 
 ([0, 1, 3], [0, 3, 4]), 
 ([0, 2, 3], [0, 1, 4]), 
 ([0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 4])]
```